# Memory usage keep growing too large with Python's multiprocessing.pool.imap

Tags: python

I'm trying to perform some costly scientific calculation with Python. I have read a data set into a list (**data_list**) with **18** elements, and each element is also a list with **1500000** int numbers. 
Now, I want to do some calculation between each pair of data in the list (**data_list**). Since each process take a long time and I have some 8 processors to use, I'm trying to use the **Pool** method from **Multiprocessing**.

```
def calc_func(args):
    # do some calculation, and return result and score
    # len(_res) == 1500000
    return _res, score


count = len(data_list)
pairs = [(i, j, data_list[i], data_list[j]) for i in range(0, count - 1) for j in range(i + 1, count)]
chunk_size, extra = divmod(len(pairs), 4 * 8)
if extra:
    chunk_size += 1
pool = Pool(8)
res = pool.imap(calc_func, pairs, chunksize=chunk_size)
pool.close()
pool.join()
```

And then, I sort the result list by **score** and append the first one to the **data_list**.

```
res.sort(key=lambda e: e[2], reverse=True) 
data_list.append(res.pop(0))
```

After that, do calculation between the just append one and each other in the **data_list**, and append the first one in the calculation result to **data_list** sorted by the **score**. This processing need to be repeat 60 times.

```
loop = 0
while loop <= 60:
    loop += 1
    count = len(data_list)
    j = count - 1
    pairs = [(i, j, data_list[i], data_list[j]) for i in range(j)]
    chunk_size, extra = divmod(len(pairs), 4 * 8)
    if extra:
        chunk_size += 1
    pool = Pool(8)
    res = pool.imap(calc_func, pairs, chunksize=chunk_size)
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
    res.sort(key=lambda e: e[2], reverse=True) 
    data_list.append(res.pop(0))
```

At beginning, the code works fine. But when loop=40, all system memory has been used and the status of each process is not running but sleeping as shown in system monitor. How should I improve my code to run faster and use less memory.

My Python version is 2.7 and my OS is Centos 7 with 16GB memory.

Comment: I really haven't worked with this kind of data, but it seems that the libraries `numpy` and `scipy` might be useful? Dunno, really (just trying to throw some ideas here)

Comment: It looks like you are trying to get the largest item. Don't use `sort()`, use `max()` instead. It is far more efficient.

Comment: @BorrajaX Thanks for your advice. The **calc_func** is used to do xor between each pair elements of two list(length is 1500000), then the result list also has 1500000. How should I use the `numpy` and `scipy`?

Comment: @KlausD. the **res** is a list [([...], score), ...], I need to get the tuple with the max score. Thanks for your advice, I'll use max() to replace sort()